# Forcing Zeitgeist to index Dropbox folder

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, dropbox, zeitgeist

I am running Ubuntu 11.10, and I would like to force Zeitgeist to index my Dropbox folder. I understand that Zeitgeist is a passive service that logs particular events (such as opening or downloading files) for later searches, but I have large Dropbox folder that was downloaded without being logged by Zeitgeist.

Short of manually opening and closing all files in my Dropbox folder, is there a way to have Zeitgeist index this folder so that I can later search it using the dash? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeitgeist is not an indexing service. For Dropbox transfers to appear inside Zeitgeist, the Dropbox client itself would have to tell Zeitgeist about the events. If you want all the files under there to appear in the dash search, you'll have to open them all, probably from the file manager, so that they get added to the Zeitgeist log.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the Dash in 12.04 is also hooked up to "locate". If your Dropbox folder is in your home folder it should eventually be indexed by locate. If you don't want to wait for this to happen automatically (I don't know how long that would take) you can just run "updatedb" in a terminal to force indexing. Note that typically the locate database is owned by root, so you need to run `sudo updatedb`. Now even files not covered by zeitgeist should show in the Dash.

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-help-test-an-improved-unity-files-lens)

Comment: Nice answer, but he is running 11.10.

Comment: I appreciate the information. If I upgrade to 12.04, I'll definitely pursue your recommendation.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that. Glad, I could help you anyway.