# Force Unity Dash to index all files on Home

Tags: unity, unity-dash, indexing

Not all files on my home directory can be found via Dash, can I force Dash to index all files so I can search for any files in any depth via Dash?

Comment: Your answer is in the 2nd answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158797/forcing-zeitgeist-to-index-dropbox-folder  Zeitgeist uses "locate" so update your locale database with `locatedb`

Comment: I got this : updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'?

Comment: @Rinzwind and locatedb give command not found?

Comment: @Nur: You get that result because `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` is a protected file. To open it, you need root privileges. Be sure to include `sudo` before `updatedb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command `sudo updatedb` on the Terminal application.