# make unity file lens find all files

Tags: 14.10, unity-dash, lenses, zeitgeist

I am one of the few, that likes the idea of unity lenses and scopes :)
Unfortunately, the file lens is not finding all files from my personal folder, just some recent (I assume they are coming from zeitgeist).

How can I make my unity dash indexing all files in my home folder? Being told “No files found” while I see the file in my  File explorer is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/158813/115161) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162252), and works also on 15.04.

In your home directory type

```
sudo updatedb -U $HOME
```

the `sudo` seems necessary as it tries to create a temp file in `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` ⇒ odd